# How to pass array post request in restassured API testing?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am new to API testing and trying to figure out how i can pass post request body with a single array which contains multiple set of request and attributes in this single array in restasssured API testing.

```
{
    "Transactions":
    [ 
      {"ReferenceId":"01","Id":"0727", "TCID": "67180405816294"},
      {"ReferenceId":"02","Id":"0727", "TCID": "67180405816294"},
      {"ReferenceId":"03","Id":"0727", "TCID": "67180405816294"}

    ]
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. 

When you say the array contains multiple sets of "request and attributes" do you mean that you'd like each of the elements of the array to be submitted to the API-under-test individually? 

That is, do you wish to make 3 separate API calls, one for each array element or you wish to make one API call that includes the _entire_ array the request body?

Comment: its a one api call that includes the entire array the request body...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to post a particular object as the body of a post request using `restassured`. something like the below should work:

```
// If you are using Object Mapping (e.g. GSON or Jackson) create your test data as java objects
List<Reference> references = ...;
TransactionDTO data = new TransactionDTO(references);

// Else, not using mapping, so create test data as string:
String data = "{ \"Transactions\": [ ...]}";

given()
  .contentType("application/json")
  .body(data)
  .queryParam("key", "value") //omit if not needed
when()
  .post("/post/url/path")
then()
  .<whatever assertions you need to make>
```

Reference: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage