# How to send Request as Json Array in body for Post using REST Assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

below is my JSON Array Request

```
[   {
    "EMPid": 320,
    "username": "string34",
    "firstName": "string34",
    "lastName": "string34",
    "email": "string@strin.com",
    "password": "string",
    "phone": "string",
    "userStatus": 0   
} ]
```

and the requirement is to send this request in body using post in REST ASSURED

i have created POJO code as below

```
public class empdet
{
    public String EMPid;
    public String username;
    and so on..

    //constructor for passing data
     ........
   // getters and setters
      .......

}
```

now how send this Request in body for POST

can anybody  help me thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the method `given().body(new Empdet(params))`, also add some of your rest-assured code

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and I found a solution using `Collections.singletonList(request)`

After creating the POJO class build your request and pass that request into `Collections.singletonList(request)`

1. Create POJO class according to your JSON Request:

   ```
   public class EmpdetRequest
   {
       public String EMPid;
       public String username;
       and so on..;

       //constructor for passing data
        ........
       // getters and setters
         .......

   }
   ```
2. Build the `Request`:

   ```
   public class RequestBuilder {

      EmpdetRequest request;

       public RequestBuilder(String EMPid) {
           request = new EmpdetRequest();
           request.setEmId(EMPid);
           //... and so on

       }

       public EmpdetRequest build() {
           return request;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create the `Test` class to consume this:

   ```
   @Test
   public void shouldAbleToSendRequest() throws IOException {
       EmpdetRequest request = new RequestBuilder("df","", ...).build();
       Collections.singletonList(request);
   }
   ```
4. Use `Collections.singletonList(request);` for sending request as JSON Array in POST method body

Answer (score -1):

You need to start with checking documentation [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage)

Note, JSON which is getting sent to the server should be valid.

Example:

```
String yourJsonAsString = "Your JSON here"; // properly escaped

given()
  .contentType("application/json")
  .body(yourJsonAsString)
  .when()
  .post("/post/url/path")
  .then()
  .body... or any other asserts you need.
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45445309)