# how to pass Array of objects as request body in restassured java

Tags: java, json, testing, automation, rest-assured

Below is my Request,

```
[
  {
    "userId": "value1"
    
 },{
    "userId": "value2"
    
  }
]
```

I tried creating POJO class and build the request and also used ArrayList but something wrong in request body

Comment: can you please share how you are receiving it in the controller ? and what is that "something wrong" that you are referring to ?

Comment: I solved a similar kind here( https://stackoverflow.com/a/70951194/11412203 ) the issue is I can create an Array of a single object but I need to pass multiple objects in Array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do List<User>.class so try using ParameterizedTypeReference

Answer (score 0):

Found answer for the below Request,

API request body,

```
[
  {
    "userId": "value1"
 },{
    "userId": "value2"
  }
]
```

Solution :

```
public String sendingRequest(String uid, String uid1){

   JSONObject user1 = new JSONObject();
   user1.put("userId", uid);

   JSONObject user2 = new JSONObject();
   user2.put("userId", uid1);

   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
   jsonArray.put(user1);
   jsonArray.put(user2);

   String jsonStr = jsonArray.toString();

   System.out.println("jsonString: "+jsonStr);
   return jsonStr;
}
```

Outcome:

```
[{"userId":"ljtdmm"},{"userId":"BBLSHl"}]
```